# Jackson json to java object mapping

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

If I pass a JSON like

```
`{
"entity":{
"name":"xyz",
"age":21
}
}`
```

Then , is it compulsory that my `POJO` should have both "`name`" and "`age`" instance variables. I mean, if I have only "name" instance field, will there be any exception while mapping?

Comment: do you try it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it compulsory that my POJO should have both "name" and "age" instance variables

If you mean "have" as in the same names exactly, then no. You can use annotations to rename the values.

If you instead mean the class definition "contains" those values, then also it shouldn't need them. That depends on how you configure `ObjectMapper`, though. For example, there is [an `AnyGetter` annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#serialization-details) that will allow you to collect "extra" JSON values. Therefore, it makes sense that mandatory fields are not required.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON contains extra fields which are not present in POJO, it will throw an exception. To avoid that you can ignore additional fields using this annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties. 
if field names are different, you can define at field getter using @jsonProperty.  (for deserialization).
for serialization use annotation on the setter method.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Pojo {
    private String name;

    @jsonProperty("firstName")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```